# Rewrite matlab code for hardware

Tags: fpga, matlab, hardware

I am working on implementation of PLL.

The implementation in MATLAB is done.  It should be simulated in a similar way in hardware.
Honestly, I don’t understand what a simulation in hardware means. Does anyone explain it to me?

I have read the software engineers use FPGA for software development. I am familiar with FPGA a lit a bit, like how to describe board in Xilinx, or switch a led on/off…such simple stuff.

Does a simulation in hardware mean to rewrite it for FPGA?

Please, could you give me some example how such code looks like

EDIT 1: PLL will be a part of the receiver. The main my task is simulation a receiver

Comment: this really, really, really sounds like you should have a call / meeting with your supervisor to ask them about your task! I bet they can help you put all this into context. "I don't understand what my task is" is something that, if you can't answer it through own research, you need to talk with your supervisor about! As soon as possible! They are not going to be mad about that, I promise: asking early when it becomes clear that you need help understanding something is what **I** want my students to do, as I can then, with my whole contextual knowledge of what they're doing, can help them.

Comment: Use your supervisor as tool to make progress: They know all about your task, and point you in the right direction. We don't really know your task, and let's face it, if you don't understand your task, either, then it's hard to even ask good questions about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PLL is sufficiently straightforward and analogue that simulating it in hardware doesn't make much sense. Just go ahead and build it, and see how it behaves.

There might be a case for simulation if you couldn't get hold of some of the components, but still wanted to have a hardware model of the loop to integrate into something else. Say you couldn't get some microwave VCO and PSD yet, so built something round a 4046 with the same bandwidth and loop filters.

Another case might be to simulate the VCO's frequency to phase response as an integrator, so that you could build the loop and loop filters, and see how they responded with the ability to probe 'phase' (the integrator output voltage representing phase) directly on an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

Simulated in hardware, or simulated as a hardware design? They are different things.

Simulated as a hardware design might mean simulated using a spice type circuit simulator with your loop built out of opamps resistors and caps, and the phase detector done as some suitable implementation of a type I or II detector (generally either flipflops or a mixer of some sort).

Simulated in hardware does not make a lot of sense for a PLL unless you are really doing a discrete time version, where simulating the implementation in something like an FPGA or ASIC might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Mathworks has a product called HDL CODER toolbox that allows you to translate MATLAB into synthesizeable VHDL which can then be put on an FPGA.

https://www.mathworks.com/products/hdl-coder.html

You could try looking into that.